# how to check ffmpeg if install on centos/php

Tags: centos, php, ffmpeg

hi there how can I be sure that ffmpeg is install in my server...

I tried this php code to check:

```
<?php

    $ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('which ffmpeg')); // or better yet:
$ffmpeg = trim(shell_exec('type -P ffmpeg'));

    if (empty($ffmpeg))
{
    die('ffmpeg not available');
}

shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ...');?>
```

It return me 'ffmpeg not available' but my server admin tell me it is install!

I have access also centos consol

Comment: Ask your server admin what the path to ffmpeg is then use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the following command,

ffmpeg -version

The above command should show you the FFMPEG Version information if Installed.